# How to put file on firebase storage in ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I am using cordovaCamera plugin to get file url in my ionic app.

I wish to put this file on firebase storage **not as base64** .

Here is my code for reference

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
.then(function(imageData) { 
var pthref = firebase.storage().ref().child("a/b");
pthref.put(WHAAT SHOULD GO HERE).then(function(snapshot) {
alert('file uploaded!');
},
function(a)
{
alert("error"+JSON.stringify(a))});
},
function(err) {
alert("Camera Error")
});
```

Comment: "imageData" looks like the most logical one. Is it not working ?

Comment: imageData returns path of the file. I need to put Blob or file object

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it works you will need to use `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` to get the URL of the image.

Then, you can get the Blob from this image with `cordova-plugin-file` (don't forget to add it) and send it to Firebase.

This code could have syntax mistake I am converting it from Ionic 2 code.

```
var options = {
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
};
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
    .then(function (fileUrl) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileUrl, (fileEntry) => {
            fileEntry.file((file) => {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                let imgBlob = new Blob([ this.result ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
                // Send file to firebase here
                var pthref = firebase.storage().ref().child("a/b");
                pthref.put(imgBlob);
                };
                reader.onerror = (error) => {
                console.error(error);
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            }, (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        })
    },
    function (err) {
        alert("Camera Error")
    });
```

Comment: I am developing on ionic1. Morever `cordova-plugin-file` could not resolve path in IOS . I cant use this plugin. and I m using destinationType FILE_URI